# Python: working with huge vectors

Tags: python

I am still learning how to program in python and I have a problem regarding operations on big arrays. I have a huge array M x N where M = 3 500 000 and N = 17 000 000 and for each vector in range(0, M) I need to iterate through all values from (0, N) and do something. My problem is that this takes very very long. I think it took somewhere between 5 and 10 minutes to process only the first item.

Could you please let me know how can I speed things up?

```
sizeV = 17 000 000

def most_similar(i, n=10):
    sim_list = []
    for k in range(0, sizeV):
        result_b = spatial.distance.correlation(vect[i], vect[k])
        sim_list.append(tuple((k, result_b)))
    L = sorted(sim_list, key = itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
    return L[:topn]
```

Comment: i've got a feeling `spatial.distance.correlation(vect[i], vect[k])` is pretty slow.  you could try using `pandas` with `apply`. alternatively, does the operation have to act on each entry? Some entries may be wildly dissimilar to vect[i], so maybe you can do a short operation to toss them out. Also, consider parallellizing.

Comment: use numpy. it's very fast, designed for big arrays and provide many array manipulation routines. edit: how come you're using scipy but not numpy?

Comment: agree with @bobrobbob, python and especially scipy have libraries that use C under the hood.  They're designed to run faster.

Answer (score 1):

Just use [numpy](http://www.numpy.org). It's designed to deal with large arrays and matrices and provides great speed/space optimizations.